# CefSharp OnBeforeDownload handler opening Open file window instead of save window

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

I am using CefSharp[49] in my windows project
The download handler is used to cancel the download according to specific condition.

Below is my handler, the problem I am facing is that the window opening is the 'Open File' window instead of 'Save as' window.

```
public void OnBeforeDownload(IBrowser browser, DownloadItem downloadItem, IBeforeDownloadCallback callback)
        {
            if (!callback.IsDisposed)
            {
                using (callback)
                {
                    if (_allowDownload)
                        callback.Continue(downloadItem.SuggestedFileName, showDialog: true);
                    else
                        downloadItem.IsCancelled = !_allowDownload;
                }
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Does the problem reproduce using the latest version? `51.0.0`. Older versions such as `49.0.0` are no longer supported. You can of course show your own dialog to work around the problem.

Comment: I need to use .Net framework 4 and cant use higher versions now. Anyway i am gonna use my own dialogbox to handle this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i used the below code as a workaround

```
  public void OnBeforeDownload(IBrowser browser, DownloadItem downloadItem, IBeforeDownloadCallback callback)
    {
        if (!callback.IsDisposed)
        {
            using (callback)
            {
                if (_allowDownload)
                {
                    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
                    saveFileDialog.FileName = downloadItem.SuggestedFileName;
                    saveFileDialog.Filter ="|*"+ System.IO.Path.GetExtension(saveFileDialog.FileName);

                    if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK && saveFileDialog.FileName != "")
                    {
                        downloadItem.SuggestedFileName = saveFileDialog.FileName;                            
                    }
                    else
                        **downloadItem.IsCancelled = _allowDownload;**
                }
                else
                    **downloadItem.IsCancelled = !_allowDownload;**

                callback.Continue(downloadItem.SuggestedFileName, showDialog: false);
            }

        }
    }

    public void OnDownloadUpdated(IBrowser browser, DownloadItem downloadItem, IDownloadItemCallback callback)
    {

        if (downloadItem.IsComplete || downloadItem.IsCancelled)
            browser.CloseBrowser(true);
    }
```

Comment: @amaitland is this the right way to cancel the download (marked with ** in the above code) ?

Comment: `By default the download will be canceled.`, only call `callback.Continue` when you wish to allow the download.

Comment: I comment out callback.Continue, but the OnDownloadUpdated keep called, why?